# Have I broken npm?

Tags: node.js, npmjs

I published an npm module about a day ago and have bumped the version a couple of times since then. In the beginning, there was 0.0.0, then 0.0.1, now sitting at 0.1.1.

When I visit the https://www.npmjs.com/package/skipper-minio everything looks okay - versions, published date, my stupid face are all there.

The 'issue' I'm seeing though, is that when you do a search that returns said module using either of the web interface at npmjs.com or the npm command line utility the version is still at 0.0.0, the published date is 'Invalid'/'prehistoric' and the description and other meta stuff is unavailable.

**Command line search result**

```
$ npm search skipper-minio
NAME                      | DESCRIPTION          | AUTHOR          | DATE        | VERSION  | KEYWORDS
skipper-minio             |                      |                 | prehistoric | 0.0.0    |
```

**Web search result**
[image]

Actually installing the module in a 'fresh' project with `npm install --save skipper-minio` or `skipper-minio@latest` both do what they should and install the actual latest 0.1.1 version.

So, is this just a matter of caching at the npmjs.com / npms.io side, is my [package.json](https://github.com/texh/skipper-minio/blob/master/package.json) breaking things, or is something more mischievous afoot?

Comment: I have the same problem with my lib stemmer_es. The worst thing is that when you look for the package in npmjs.com it does not appear. The same with npm search. Also, just in case, I validated the name of my package with validate-npm-package-name and it is correct

Comment: @lopezezequiel I think it's something to do with [npms.io](https://npms.io/). The search pages on npmjs.com mention this service below search results. Check out the API results for [your module](https://api.npms.io/v2/package/stemmer_es). Looks like it's giving the same errors for both our modules & isn't updating other recently updated npm packages either.

Comment: I updated my repository with some changes and republish the package with a new version but stays as before.

Comment: It's working now. It must have been a problem of npmjs

Comment: FWIW if anyone else finds this question there's an open incident at https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/qg46dsfk1vt2