# published npm package not searchable

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I published an npm package named **container-object-model** but currently, it's not visible in [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com).

[image]

but I can install it using `yarn add container-object-model`.

(files in node_modules)

[image]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "container-object-model",
  "version": "0.0.5",
  "description": "Container Object Model",
  "main": "./dist/container-object-model.js",
  "types": "./dist/container-object-model.d.ts",
  "keywords": ["container-object-model", "container"],
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "npm run build",
    "start": "webpack",
    "build": "webpack --env=build",
    "postbuild": "tsc ./src/container-object-model.ts --declaration --esModuleInterop --outDir ./dist --emitDeclarationOnly",
    "demo": "webpack-dev-server --env=demo"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/rannie-peralta/container-object-model.git"
  },
  "author": "Rannie Peralta",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/rannie-peralta/container-object-model/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/rannie-peralta/container-object-model#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "typescript": "^3.4.3",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/lodash.throttle": "^4.1.6",
    "@types/memoizee": "^0.4.2",
    "@types/shortid": "^0.0.29",
    "decimal.js": "^10.1.1",
    "lodash.throttle": "^4.1.1",
    "memoizee": "^0.4.14",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "shortid": "^2.2.14"
  }
}
```

Also here is the other issue I found when I tried to import it:

[image]

Comment: Indexing takes time and might not take effect instantly, wait and check later.

Comment: But how about the issue on importing the package? Is my types declaration correct? It says it can't find the module.

Comment: Make sure your `package.json` has the correct "main" field, OR you need to have a top level `index.js` right in your module folder. Either will do.

Comment: I think the `main` field in the `package.json` is correct because I imported and used it in another project and it's working. My only confusion now is why the IDE (Visual Studio Code) is complaining that the module can't find.

Comment: Possible solutions: 1. Quit and restart vscode, sometimes it just stucks. 2. Turn on TS `traceResolution` option to debug why TS can't find your module.

Comment: Yes. restarting the vscode solve that error.

I tried it before but I didn't notice that I have to close all the vscode windows.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Re: the web search portion of the question, have experienced something similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761863/have-i-broken-npm
That said installation/usage of the npm package still works (it's installable just not properly searchable)